# No uploaded assets sprite for a rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just pushed my first app on Heroku and it appears that my sprite images have not been uploaded to the server. Do you have any clue of what could have happened ?

For example :
My file is **app/assets/images/app_photo.png**

My CSS file define my sprite with : `background: url("app_photo.png");`

In my app, I found the link to my sprite, but when I click on it, the **herokuapp.com/assets/app_photo.png** path renders "The page you were looking for doesn't exist".

Here are the logs of my push to heroku :

```
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 37.9MB
-----> Launching... done, v17
```

When I replace `background: url("app_photo.png");` with `background: image-url("app_photo.png");`, here is the precompiled css :

```css
.app_photo{background:url(/assets/app_photo-f095c78ecb698e651f262b36a593dc8e.png);height:64px;width:64px;text-indent:-9999px}
```

Comment: did you get precompile error while pushing the app to heroku?

Comment: did you add your /assets folder to git?

Comment: Yes, I did all [that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the Rails assets Pipeline, you **should** reference your assets in a **SCSS** file using:

```
image-url("your_image.png")
```

See [Rails Asset Pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) for more information.

Using Heroku you have 3 choices:

1. Compiling assets locally.
2. Compiling assets during slug compilation.
3. Compiling assets during runtime.

See [heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) for more information.

In your `config/production.rb` file:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Heroku Cedar architecture is not able to serve static assets.

Comment: Do I must replace `background: url("app_photo.png");` by `background: image-url("app_photo.png")` ?

Comment: If you want to use the asset pipeline, yes. Look here to know why http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

Comment: it's `image-url` not `image_url`.

Comment: Yes, it's what I did in my CSS. I made an error only in the comment.

Comment: My CSS file is called `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss`, I replaced all `url` by `image-url`, but it changes nothing, there is no `app_photo.png` (for example) to be found...

Comment: Ok, try to let heroku compile the assets for you. Remove from git `public/assets/` and push to heroku.